# Installing Comfast CF-917AC drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers

I purchased this [CF-917AC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H8Z5ERI)

It works fine with Windows and is honestly decent, but I try to install the drivers for Linux on Ubuntu (latest distro) and I'm at a block.

I can't find anything explaining how to install the one I need in the Linux folder provided in the CD [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/idrdxjo55q33ve1/AADWcRo67NUni_9vTVD5dAWoa?dl=0)

I need the RTL8814AU, the other folders contain a readme, yet this one doesn't and when I try to use install.sh I get authentication errors no matter how I run it. I'm new to Linux and don't even want to start doing anything with it until I have internet enabled.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command. And what is the kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully built the rtl8814au driver for use with the Comfast CF-917AC USB WiFi adapter on Debian Stretch (Kernel: 4.9.0-3-amd64) from [this source](https://github.com/astsam/rtl8812au.git) with the following command: make RTL8814=1  Incidentally, that driver is purported to support monitor mode and frame injection as mentioned here.

While I realize this doesn't exactly answer your question, at least it's a relevant response to your inquiry after four months of no other such responses.

Additionally, there is a thread [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=234143&start=20#p1248080) you may find of interest.

It's time this driver was included in the distro...